# recurring ambiguous column name _id sqlite error in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried editing my code according to the suggestion i found on this site,but nothing seems to work..i still keep getting the following logcat error:

```
03-24 11:44:27.037: E/AndroidRuntime(1809): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: 
CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT _id AS _id,   fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber,   customerPlotNumber, _id FROM customers AS customers  
INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON customerMeterId =_id
```

The class referenced above in logcat:

```
public class ViewCustomers {

public static final String TABLE_CUSTOMER_VIEW = "customerView";

public static final String CUSTOMER_VIEW_ID = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID;
public static final String CUSTOMER_VIEW_FIRSTNAME = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_FIRST_NAME;
public static final String CUSTOMER_VIEW_LASTNAME = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_LAST_NAME;
public static final String CUSTOMER_VIEW_METER = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_NUMBER;
public static final String CUSTOMER_VIEW_PLOT = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_PLOT_NUMBER;
public static final String CUSTOMER_VIEW_KEY_METER_ID = CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID;

private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_VIEW = ""
        + "CREATE VIEW " + TABLE_CUSTOMER_VIEW 
        + " AS SELECT "+ CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID+" AS _id,"+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_FIRST_NAME+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_LAST_NAME+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_NUMBER+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_PLOT_NUMBER+","+
        " "+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID+""+
        " FROM "+CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS+" AS customers "+" INNER JOIN "+MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+" AS meters"+
        " ON "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID+" ="+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID;


public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(CREATE_CUSTOMER_VIEW);
}

public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {
    Log.w(ViewCustomers.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " + ViewCustomers.TABLE_CUSTOMER_VIEW);
    onCreate(database);
}
```

I've even used aliases but still no solution.Now i don't know how else to solve it.

**EDIT**

After the corrections:

```
 private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_VIEW = ""
        + "CREATE VIEW " + TABLE_CUSTOMER_VIEW 
        + " AS SELECT "+MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+"."+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID+""+" AS "+ MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+"."+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID +","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_FIRST_NAME+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_LAST_NAME+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_NUMBER+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_PLOT_NUMBER+","+
        " "+CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS+"."+ CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID+

        " FROM "+CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS+" AS customers "+" INNER JOIN "+MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+" AS meters"+
        " ON "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_METER_ID+" ="+MeterTableDetails.TABLE_METERS+"."+MeterTableDetails.METER_ID;
```

**EDIT 2**

```
03-24 13:58:24.687: I/create statement(3098): CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT meters._id AS   meters._id, fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber, 
customerPlotNumber, customers._id FROM customers AS customers  
INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON customerMeterId = meters._id
```

Comment: it could be that the meters table has _id as a column also.

Comment: That's true..all my tables have the column '_id'..but i thought that was okay as long as i use aliases to reference them in my query?

Comment: no probably not. use tablename._id and you will be done

Comment: okay..i would be happy if that would put me out of my misery..could you please use my code like from the above example to show me what you mean?Just so that i know i'm following..

Comment: OR you could use `AS _id1` instead of `AS _id`...

Comment: @naffie - try the query, used ur code for better understanding

Comment: @Vyger i also tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to get rid of the error: Here's the first part of the create statement:               private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_VIEW = ""
            + "CREATE VIEW " + TABLE_CUSTOMER_VIEW 
      + " AS SELECT "+CustomerTableDetails.TABLE_CUSTOMERS+"."+ CustomerTableDetails.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID+" AS _id1,"+
      " "+CustomerTableDetails.KEY_FIRST_NAME+","+

Comment: @naffie you managed to solve it ?

Comment: NO..not at all :-( i saw some misplaced quotes somewhere in the query,edited them and thought it would work but i still get the syntax error near "." in my logcat.

Comment: cud you print the query in the logcat using Log and post that in ur question?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille sure..right away

Comment: do you need the alias meters._id ??? that is as meters._id ??? an alias is a column name remove the . from the column name

Comment: @naffie welcome.. glad it worked eventually :). happy coding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use tablename._id in order to refer to _id in the query above

change:

```
CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT _id AS _id,
fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber, 
customerPlotNumber, _id FROM customers AS customers  
INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON customerMeterId =_id
```

to

```
CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT customers._id AS _id, 
fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber,   customerPlotNumber, 
_id FROM customers AS customers  
INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON 
customerMeterId =customers._id // or meters._id -> whatever you think suits
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT meters._id AS _id, 
fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber,   customerPlotNumber, 
_id FROM customers AS customers  
INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON customerMeterId =meters._id
```

Comment: I have edited my code as you suggested but now i get this logcat error:  03-24 12:17:35.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1931): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT customers._id AS _id, fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber, customerPlotNumber, _id FROM customers AS customers  INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON customerMeterId =meters._id

Comment: you have ,_id next to FROM change that also

Comment: okay, i changed that too, but now there's a new error :  03-24 12:28:26.157: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: customers._id (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW customerDetails AS SELECT customers._id AS _id, customers.fName, customers.lName, customers.address, customers.email, customers.phone, customers.accountNumber, customers.customerMeterNumber, customers.customerPlotNumber

Comment: I think you better change the `AS _id` part to `AS tablename._id`

Comment: @naffie Vyger is correct, and it wud be nice if you could post in the whole query.

Comment: the logcat error is different now..so perhaps we're getting closer to the solution.This is what it says:                   03-24 12:46:59.597: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW customerView AS SELECT meters._id AS meters._id fName, lName, customerMeterId, customerMeterNumber, customerPlotNumber, customers._id FROM customers AS customers  INNER JOIN meters AS meters ON customerMeterId =meters._id                                                        or maybe it is my projection string

Comment: SELECT meters._id AS meters._id fName, you have missed a comma between _id and fName

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille i have now included the comma,which i had missed before but it still says error near "."..i have edit my question above with the current query

Comment: before calling database.execSQL(CREATE_CUSTOMER_VIEW); Log the create statement and you might know whre the problem is